# Best practice to host self-maintained Debian packages on GitHub

Tags: linux, debian, git, package-management, packages

This question is especially about the best practice to host self-maintained Debian packages on GitHub. Here is my dilemma:

- It is commonly recommended not to put the `debian` folder within the source tree so as to make it easier for other distros.
- So I did. I did not put my `debian` folder within the source tree on my GitHub.
- However when building the Debian packages, the build mechanize anticipate a `debian` folder under the source tree.
- This means my GitHub repo is not directly usable for my build. This is nuisance because as a self Debian maintainer, my only focus is Debian, and I'm building my Debian package all the time, not for other distros.
- I've dealt with it and actually have a solution for myself, but when I tagged a release on GitHub, the release .tar.gz file will reflect my above folder structure, which means the 
  release .tar.gz file from GitHub is not a good candidate for upstream source. I'm OK with it, but worry it might confuse others.

Is there any easy way to manage it? E.g., can I tell GitHub only take a sub-folder for my release .tar.gz file? Or anything? The last thing I want to do is to separate my current arrangement into two, because when I change things, the changes will equally spread between the source and `debian` folder. Separate them into two will lost such internal connection/logic.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I'd say that if other distros don't want to use your debian directory, they're free to remove it in their build script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well each way has advantages and disadvantages. But from your description, single developer with Debian as main target. I would recommend keeping Debian native package, I mean `debian` in part of source tree. Even for major OS's that have big user share, like RPM.

I faced similar thing before for a project with low resources. We setup an Launchpad PPA (Build recipe), it does support source and packaging from separate repository or separate branches even custom path for debian folder. It does do build with each commit. But with time and code changes and specially continuous refactoring, It became a lot of effort to keep it updated and working. We end up setting it to build on request or when we update packaging branch, which it usually means we are preparing a release.

So if you want a quick and continuous delivery for specific platform, then keep it part of the code. Otherwise, make packaging separate and do periodic releases, like Debian developers workflow.

Comment: I'll accept it, because, after nearly 10 years, this is the only answer I got. But honestly, I'm still keeping debian folder away from the source tree on my GitHub, because my debian folders are hosted on salsa.debian.org now.